# How to have access to new LinkedIn Api

Tags: linkedin-api

we have an Plugin for an CRM-Software on Mac. With our plugin we want to show LinkedIn Contacts of an Person. So that you have an fast access to them. The problem with the new API is that the permission ‚r_network‘ is running out. Is that correct ? Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem ? Do i have to join a partner program or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001814/linkedin-api-get-public-profile-from-e-mail).

Pulling profile information from Linkedin is not very easy in terms of pulling a specific public user profile.

If you want to pull a profile you need to meet one of the requirements below.

1. Have a special partnership with LinkedIn which allows you access to
   non-public API functions. This is very hard, and per my
   understanding, they only consider big guys (Startups with serious
   funding, established companies...)
2. Retrieve the user's details from another social network via email
   (Facebook used to allow that, not sure these days), and then perform
   a faceted search in LinkedIn's API using details other than the
   email (name, job title, location...) . You will get accurate results
   lots of times.
3. Use a 3rd party service such as fullcontact.com in order to get you
   those results.

Note the above was copied from linked [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001814/linkedin-api-get-public-profile-from-e-mail).

For more information on integrating with linkedin, check their API. Their [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs) is great and they have an awesome [tool](https://apigee.com/resources/linkedin) to test their api.