# How to get linked in profile information by e-mail adress Linked-in API

Tags: linkedin-api

I have some mail adresses and trying to get linked in profile information like titles,photos... by e-mail address.
I can easily get those information by using username with the Linked in API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

I have also followed the docs to get data:https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/email-lookup-api
and im getting Not Found 404.
I've tried many other manuel ways but i can't figure out.

edit:I also checked this article but the answer is really old [LinkedIn API: GET public profile from e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001814/linkedin-api-get-public-profile-from-e-mail)   
im still searching other ways any help would be appreciated

Comment: For now, i found one more current solution [handle-lookup-API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/handle-lookup) but needs to have partnership which Samer mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001814/linkedin-api-get-public-profile-from-e-mail